# python : easy substring/parsing

Tags: python, string, parsing, substring

I have such a string

```
 <img src="http://www.askgamblers.com/cache/97299a130feb2e59a08a08817daf2c0e6825991f_begado-casino-logo-review1.jpg" /><br/>
 Begado is the newest online casino in our listings. As the newest
 member of the Affactive group, Begado features NuWorks slots and games
 for both US and international players.
<img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/AskgamblesCasinoNews/~4/SXhvCskjiYo" height="1" width="1"/>
```

i need to get `src` from first `img` tag

can i do it anyway easy?

Comment: Anytime I see HTML, my brain immediately goes to BeautifulSoup (http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html). Check here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815747/beautifulsoup-getting-href) for a similar question.

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12937144/image-scraping-program-in-python-not-functioning-as-intended

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For HTML screen-scraping in python, I recommend the [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) library.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
images = list(soup.findAll('img'))
print images[0]['src']
```

Answer (score 2):

Obligatory "don't parse HTML with regex" warning: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/505154

Evil regex solution:

```
import re
re.findall(r'<img\s*src="([^"]*)"\s*/>', text)
```

This will return a list with the `src` attribute for every `<img>` tag that *only* contains a `src` attribute (since you said you only want to match the first one).

Answer (score 0):

One way to to this would be to use [regex](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

Another way is to [split](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) the string by quotes and then take the second element that is returned.

```
splits = your_string.split('"')
print splits[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick and ugly way to do it without any library:

```
"""
    >>> get_src(data)
    ['http://www.askgamblers.com/cache/97299a130feb2e59a08a08817daf2c0e6825991f_begado-casino-logo-review1.jpg', 'http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/AskgamblesCasinoNews/~4/SXhvCskjiYo']
"""

data = """<img src="http://www.askgamblers.com/cache/97299a130feb2e59a08a08817daf2c0e6825991f_begado-casino-logo-review1.jpg" /><br/>
 Begado is the newest online casino in our listings. As the newest
 member of the Affactive group, Begado features NuWorks slots and games
 for both US and international players.
<img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/AskgamblesCasinoNews/~4/SXhvCskjiYo" height="1" width="1"/>"""

def get_src(lines):
    srcs = []
    for line in data.splitlines():
        i = line.find('src=') + 5
        f = line.find('"', i)
        if i > 0 and f > 0:
            srcs.append(line[i:f])
    return srcs
```

However I would recomend using [Beatiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), its a really nice library designed to deal with the real
web (broken HTML and all) or you could use [Element Tree](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) from Python standard library if your data is valid XML.